# Function parameters hint Eclipse with PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Seems like newbie's question, but I just can't find the answer. Can I somehow see function parameters hint like in Visual Studio by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Space when cursor is in function call like this:

```
someObj.doSomething("Test", "hello, wold", 4|)
```

where | is my cursor position. Ctrl+Spase shows me that information when I start typing function name, but I want to see function's parameters list at any time I want. I'm using latest available Eclipse and PyDev

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try "`CTRL+space`" after a '`,`', not after a parameter.
The function parameters are displayed just after the '`(`' or after a '`,`' + "`CTRL+space`".

Answer (score 3):

Parameters will show up just after a '(', which is how I re-displayed mine for ages. I recently discovered that 'CTRL + Shift + Space' will show the parameters anywhere in a function call. Saved me some valuable seconds.