# Function parameters in Eclipse/PyDev

Tags: eclipse, pydev

How do I display the function parameters help box when I'm in the middle of typing them? By looking at questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969466/function-parameters-hint-eclipse-with-pydev), it seems that I have to hit either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>, but neither of these seems to work. The parameters are displayed when I type the <kbd>(</kbd>, but then they disappear.

BTW, a related question: It seems that when I'm typing the name of a class the parameters box isn't displayed. I have to type `.__init__` after the class name to see the help box. Is this like this or am I missing something?

Comment: So, anyone know about this problem?

Answer (score 2):

My PyDev (1.5.1.1258496115) will auto complete the function parameters if I stick the cursor between the parentheses after a function:

`my_func(` | `)` +  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> = `my_func(param1, param2)`

Comment: What do you mean by auto completing? I want the box that tells me what the parameters are to appear, is that what you're saying?

Comment: Ctrl+Space should be able to do both:

* add the parameters that are not there
* bring the tooltip if parameters are already there

Comment: @Fabio Zadrozny:Ctrl+Space seem not working with the latest Eclipse and PyDev on Windwos XP

Comment: @yorua007 it does work for me: please create an issue in the tracker with your specific use-case.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a weird situation.When i typed in the following code:

```
wx.SplitterWindow.__init__(|)
```

and press `ALT+\`, nothing popped up.So i continued to type in `se` and then press`ALT+\`:

[image]

then i delete `se` char by char:

[image]